# Setup Vuforia in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to use Vuforia with Unity but I am getting some error:

> error CS1704: An assembly with the same name
>   `Vuforia.UnityExtensions.Editor' has already been imported. Consider
>   removing one of the references or sign the assembly C:/Program
>   Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/VuforiaSupport/Managed/Editor/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.Editor.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   Assets/Vuforia/Editor/Scripts/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.Editor.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>
> error CS1704: An assembly with the same name `Vuforia.UnityExtensions'
>   has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references or
>   sign the assembly C:/Program
>   Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/VuforiaSupport/Managed/Runtime/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/Internal/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll (Location
>   of the symbol related to previous error)

Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

Here is screenshot of the Console log:

[image]

Comment: Please properly format your question and only include images of they add something valuable (your pic for example on shows the same error message you already posted in your question). Additionally, it's not obvious what your question is and it might be helpful to include the relevant parts if your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

The old Vuforia plugin is interfering with the new one.

**1**.Close Unity

**2**.Delete the current Vuforia plugin folder at `<ProjectDirectory>/Assets/Vuforia` at any other Vuforia related folders or files in your project.

**Setup Vuforia with the integrated version:**

Unity integrated Vuforia engine in their Engine in the 2017.2 version and this is the only one you should now be using.

**3**.Run the "UnityDownloadAssistant.exe" for your current Unity version. Only select the "Vuforia Augmented Reality Support" then install it on top of your Unity version.

[image]

**4**.You can now open Unity. You will now see the Vuforia option under the GameObject menu. You no longer need the plugin to be in the project.

[image]

**5**.Finally, enable Vuforia by going to *File* --> *Build Settings...* --> *Player Settings* --> *XR Settings* and checking the "Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported" checkbox.

[image]